# Break loop over TypeScript object properties

Tags: loops, typescript

I would like to iterate over object properties with TypeScript. But I would like to stop as soon as a specific object has been found.

Something like:

```
function hasElement() {
    let obj = {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
        c: 'c'
    }
    let found = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.obj).length && !found; i++) {
        let prop = obj[i];
        found = prop === 'a';
    }
    return found;
}
console.log(hasElement());
```

But `obj[i]` doesn't work because the key is not a number.
Of course I could use `break` or jump to labels but it is ugly in my opinion as I would rather like to specify the loop condition in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how you iterate an object with TypeScript. You're looking for `for..of`:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  if (obj[key] === 'a') { return true; }
}
return false;
```

You can also use `.find()`:

```
const matchingKey = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === 'a');
return Boolean(matchingKey); // convert to boolean.
```

Comment: The condition is based on the property value not the key. But the `find()` based solution was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Both solutions use the value.

Comment: Ah yea, you are right. While `return` is kind of a break I like it more than `break`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could use **Array.filter** or **Array.find** for that.

Array.filter will go trough the entire list but there's better support for it.

```
let found = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] == 'a')[0]
```

Array.find should be exactly what you need but it lacks support on some browsers.

```
let found = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] == 'a');
```

IE lacks support for it. You can find the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: The condition should stop the loop at the first occurency. But the `find()` based solution was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!